# How to check installed application using googlePlay or not in android device

Tags: android

How to check that any android application was installed from Google Play Store(by clicking on Install button) or by downloaded .apk file and install it in device ?

Answer (score 0):

When installed from Google Play, you will receive a `com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER` broadcast during the install process. Simply [create a broadcast receiver](http://n3vrax.wordpress.com/2011/07/15/listen-for-install-referrer-broadcast-message-get-referrer-on-install/) for this, and have a boolean value in your `SharedPreferences` along the lines of `fromGooglePlay`, which you can set to true in the receiver.

However, I do not think you can have similar receivers for other app stores, like Amazon's.

Additionally, this will not work on Android 3.1 and above, as apps that have not been launched at least once are not eligible to receive broadcasts.

However, you can try an alternate solution:

In you app, have a constant boolean somewhere, something like `GOOGLE_PLAY_BUILD`. When building an apk for Google Play, set this to `true`, and when building an apk for manual distribution, set this to `false`. Then simply check it's value at runtime, and act accordingly.

Also, there is a [getInstallerPackageName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29) method in `PackageManager` which can be used for this purpose. However, this value is not reliable and may be tampered with.